# What has a mac address of 00:05:04:03:02:01?

Tags: wireless-router

A program "Who is on my wifi" indicates a device with a mac address of 00:05:04:03:02:01. Does anyone know what it is?
I have  Cisco router from the local ISP.

Comment: What is your ISP?

Comment: You can plug that into one of the OUI lookup sites on the Internet to discover the company which owns the OUI. More than likely, it is someone who is using a made-up MAC address.

Comment: There are google results suggesting this is an internal firewall inside a router - but they have a different router by the look of it.

Answer (score 9):

You can plug that into one of the OUI lookup sites on the Internet to discover the company which owns the OUI.

More than likely, with a pattern like `54321`, it is someone who is using a made-up MAC address. It is relatively easy to spoof a MAC address.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>The Wireshark OUI lookup tool (https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html) shows that the prefix `00:05:04` is registered to a "Naray Information & Communication Enterprise". That appears to be a component manufacturer / OEM, so no help there.</strike>

If your ISP gave you the login to your router, you could look to see what IP address and/or device has that MAC address--or even better, it might be printed on your equipment somewhere.

You could also use Google to learn how to use ARP (either by itself or with the `arping` command) to learn the IP address using that MAC. Perhaps the IP matches that of your router (the "default gateway" configured on your computer).

The preceding is good to learn, but @RonMaupin is probably right about it being spoofed.

Comment: Did you notice that it is 54321? That really appears to be a faked MAC address.

Comment: @RonMaupin I did not, nice catch. I revise my answer!

Comment: @RonMaupin add an answer so I can upvote!

Comment: OK. It did that.

Answer (score 2):

I found a similar mystery host on my network, and ended up here looking for an answer, 2+ years since the last update :). But since this page has 5K views, I thought others might still be interested in my answer.

An nMap scan of my network showed a TCP listener on 10.0.0.254:49152 (mac 00:05:04:03:02:01). (By the way, 49152 is C0:00 in hex)

In my case the culprit was my Xfinity Wireless Gateway (a Cisco model), which is set up to work at 10.0.0.1. But on the 10.0.0.254 address it seems to be hosting a server that supports the gateway's Wireless Protected Setup (WPS) feature.

I discovered that info by firing up Wireshark and watching for traffic to/from the 10.0.0.254 address. What I saw were some SSDP notification messages. These included the URL http:// 10.0.0.254:49152/wps_device.xml. Browsing that url provided model information identifying my XFinity/Cicso Gateway.

If you've got a Cisco Router/Gateway, perhaps you can skip the Wireshark step, and just try that URL on the IP your mystery host shows up at.

I haven't tried it myself yet, but I'd imagine that disabling WPS and/or UPnP (which WPS often makes use of) on the gateway might make the 254 host disappear.

Answer (score 1):

It is an ASA Cisco firewall. You'll notice the only port open is 49152 as well. I am a Cybersecurity & Forensics student. Firewalls use the 54321 MAC address a lot to make it easy to identify.

Comment: "Firewalls use the 54321 MAC address a lot" -- Could you provide any link to support this claim? Is this some kind of industry standard? or "de facto" standard? a common practice? "Firewalls use" by default or rather "admins set"?

Comment: 100% of the ASA Cisco firewalls built into modems that I have come across use MAC 54321.  I would guess and say it is "de facto" due to being mass produced, the same port (49152) is open as well. I do not see Comcast/Xfinity for example, taking the time to program each one individually. They want control of their systems and will not let users access the scripts on their modems. I cannot find documentation. The other interesting thing is that it is always on IP RANGE/24-1. For example, Subnet: 255.255.255.0 IP:10.0.0.0 = IP:10.0.0.254.